# jQuery get element height after slideDown is done

Tags: jquery

Why can't I get element's height after slideDown animation is complete? 
Simple example:

```
var height;
el.slideDown('slow', function() {
    height = $(this).outerHeight();
});
console.log(height);
```

Instead, the console returns `undefined` value. Here's live on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5826/) I would appreciate some clarification, as I am trying to learn. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The callback is executed approximately 600ms later than your `console.log` call. When you call  the `log` function, the `height` variable still holds an `undefined` value.

Comment: Oh ok.. didn't know about this before, now I know what to do, thanks undefined :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/X5826/7/) fiddle

```
$('ul').on('click', '> li > a', function (e) {
    var _this = $(this).parent(),
        el = _this.children('p'),
        opened = _this.siblings('.open');

    opened
        .removeClass('open')
        .slideUp('slow');

    if (el.is(':visible')) {
        el.slideUp(300, 'easeInBack');
        _this.removeClass('open');
    } else {
        var height;
        el.slideDown('slow', function () {
            height = _this.outerHeight();
        }).promise().done(function() {
   alert(height)});

        _this.addClass('open');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```